# One prefetch in method

Tags: c#, prefetch

I have some method on the bottom. I want to invoke this method many times but additionally I want to invoke `Session.Prefetch<OpParamDef>()` JUST once. What do I have to do? Is there any special command for this? I want to invoke `Prefetch` just for the first time.

```
public void method
{
    get
    {
        Session.Prefetch<OpParamDef>();              
        var result = new List<OpParamDef>();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a method - it's a property declaration, except it's an invalid one. Providing invalid code like this makes it very hard to help you. When you say "just once" do you mean "just once in the entire lifetime of the application" or "just once for the instance" or something else? Please clarify.

Comment: Just once in the entire lifetime of the application because I'm doing optimization and prefetch calls every time.

Comment: In that case, a static constructor would probably be enough.

Comment: Good idea. I did something like static method and inside is if instruction. It works for first invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at using `Lazy<T>` for storing a lazy loaded collection.  The documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)

An example usage based on your question might be:

```
Lazy<List<OpParamDef>> Collection { get; set; } 
//...in your ctor
Collection = new Lazy<List<OpParamDef>>(() => Session.Prefetch<OpParamDef>());
```

You can access `Collection.Value` multiple times, however `Session.Prefetch<OpParamDef>()` will only be used on the first call, the result of that initializer is then cached.

You could even hide the `Value` accessor behind a property:

```
public List<OpParamDef> CollectionAsList
{
    get
    {
        return Collection.Value;
    }
}
```

This has the benefit of not loading the initialization function at all if the value isn't used.

In addition to this you can flexibly use this approach in any context.  (Application level, request context etc.)

Comment: @RobertDaraż it looks like you're replicating the functionality of `Lazy<T>`.  I would investigate how the above solution (using 'Lazy<T>') works and consider using that.